# Powershell how to change the numbering/values in the xml file

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with .xml file.

I had to combine 3 separate .xml's and each of them had separate numbering inside of it. Let's say from 1 to 120. Now I have to re-number from 1 to 360. I tried ForEach-Object with -replace but with no effect. I was thinking about $ var ++ but I don't know how to use it properly. Xml example below:

```
**<III id_bloku="1"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"
/</III>
<III id_bloku="2"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"
/</III>
<III id_bloku="3"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"
/</III>
<III id_bloku="1"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"
/</III>
<III id_bloku="2"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"
/</III>
<III id_bloku="3"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"
/</III>
<III id_bloku="1"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"
/</III>
<III id_bloku="2"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"
/</III>
<III id_bloku="3"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"
/</III>**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple text reading and string formatting since the XML is not complete.

```
$number = 1 # number start
$(switch -regex -file x.xml {
    '^(.*?id_bloku=")\d+(".*)$' { "{0}{2}{1}" -f $matches[1],$matches[2],$number++ }
    default { $_ }
}) | Set-Content x.xml
```

`switch` with `-regex` flag will apply regex matching. `-file` reads a file line by line. `^(.*?id_bloku=")` matches from the start of a string and everything up until the first occurrence of `id_bloku="` on a line and stores it as capture group 1. `\d+` matches one or more consecutive digits. `(".*)$` matches the next `"` and the remainder of the line as capture group 2. When there is a successful match, `$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]` contain capture group 1 and 2 contents, respectively. `$matches` is an automatic variable that updates on a successful match against a single string.

`-f` is the string format operator. `{number}` is the placeholder for an item to the right side of `-f`. `{0}` is the first item, `{1}` is the second item, and so on.

---

Using an XML reader and deserializing the XML is probably the best solution. If we assume your XML is constructed as follows, you can then execute the following code:

```
# This line can be replaced with file reading instead: $xml = [xml](gc file.xml)
$xml = [xml]@'
<root>
<III id_bloku="1"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"/>
<III id_bloku="2"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"/>
<III id_bloku="3"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"/>
<III id_bloku="1"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"/>
<III id_bloku="2"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"/>
<III id_bloku="3"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"/>
<III id_bloku="1"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"/>
<III id_bloku="2"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"/>
<III id_bloku="3"  status_kontroli="0"  status_weryfikacji="P"/>
</root>
'@

$number = 1 # starting number
$xml.root.III.foreach({$_.id_bloku = ($number++).ToString()})
$xml.Save('c:\temp\output.xml')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You save my day! Of course, it works flawlessly.